# plotting histogram from csv file using matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

my csv file is very complex.. it contains numeric as well as string attributes.
this is how my csv file looks like
[image]
I want to plot a histogram of  processes versus the cpuid

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, for instance you've posted no code that loads the data or attempted any of the well documented [plotting methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#api-dataframe-plotting)

Comment: Use
[`read_csv()` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
to read the csv as a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: If there's only `cpu_id` in the second column, wouldn't it make sense to simply give the column the header "cpu_id" and remove (search/replace) everything from the fields except the values 0/1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and plot by [`hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

temp=u"""kmem_kmalloc;{cpu_id=1}
kmem_kmalloc;{cpu_id=1}
kmem_kmalloc;{cpu_id=1}
kmem_kmalloc;{cpu_id=1}
kmem_kfree;{cpu_id=1}
kmem_kfree;{cpu_id=1}
power_cpu_idle;{cpu_id=0}
power_cpu_idle;{cpu_id=0}
power_cpu_idle;{cpu_id=3}"""

s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), #after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
                sep=";", #set separator, if sep=',' can be omited (default sep = ,)
                header=None, #no header in csv
                names=[None,'cpuid'], #set names of columns, (first is None because index)
                index_col=0, #first column set to index
                squeeze=True) #try convert DataFrame to Series
print s
kmem_kmalloc      {cpu_id=1}
kmem_kmalloc      {cpu_id=1}
kmem_kmalloc      {cpu_id=1}
kmem_kmalloc      {cpu_id=1}
kmem_kfree        {cpu_id=1}
kmem_kfree        {cpu_id=1}
power_cpu_idle    {cpu_id=0}
power_cpu_idle    {cpu_id=0}
power_cpu_idle    {cpu_id=3}
Name: cpuid, dtype: object
```

```
#if max cpu <= 9, use Indexing with .str 
s = s.str[-2].astype(int)

#if cpu > 9 
#s= s.str.extract('(\d)', expand=False)
print s
kmem_kmalloc      1
kmem_kmalloc      1
kmem_kmalloc      1
kmem_kmalloc      1
kmem_kfree        1
kmem_kfree        1
power_cpu_idle    0
power_cpu_idle    0
power_cpu_idle    3
Name: cpuid, dtype: int32

plt.figure();
s.hist(alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]